# Neo4j match statement params error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am posting to Neo4j using the Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint (`http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`). My json post looks like the following.

```
"statements": [{
    statement: 'MATCH (n:user {username: {userdata}.username})\nRETURN n',
    params: {userdata: {username: 'pewpewlasers'}}
}]
```

This results in the following error:

```
{
   code: 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing',
   message: 'Expected a parameter named userdata'
}
```

I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MATCH clause accept [literals as parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/cypher-parameters.html#_string_literal). What you use are map parameters like in [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/query-merge.html#merge-using-map-parameters-with-merge)

This is what the query should look with literals :

```
"statements": [{
    statement: 'MATCH (n:user {username: {username}})\nRETURN n',
    parameters: {username: 'pewpewlasers'}
}]
```

EDIT: The new http transactional endpoint has changed the param key to parameters http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-a-transaction

Comment: yes but i am also specifying params manually `n:user {username: {userdata}.username}`. The problem you are suggesting only occurs if I use `n:user {userdata}`. In my case it's not even able to find `userdata`.

Comment: Yes that's what I say, you pass a map, but you have to pass key/value pairs in the params of the statement. You can't have {map}.property in match clauses, only {propertyKey}

Comment: But `{map}.property` in `MATCH` still works if I use `Legacy Cypher HTTP endpoint` instead of `Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint`. Any idea why?

Comment: One point though, for the http transactional endpoint, the params key has been changed to 'parameters' http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-a-transaction